# 32 bit _asm code to 64 bit assembly code on Windows filter Driver

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, driver, filter-driver

i have a driver code havin an assembly code that is using _asm (inline assembly) its working fine when i am compiling in 32 bit WDK but it throw following error:

```
"error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture"
```

please convert following _asm code for 64 bit compilation.

```
_asm
{
    mov     ebx, cr0 
    push    ebx 
    and     ebx, ~010000h 
    mov     cr0, ebx
    sti
}
```

I was use __writecr0() to set cr0 value but how can i set interrupt flag (sti) in x64 windows driver?
I have This Function

```
VOID RunHook(ULONG Service_Index,PVOID NewAddress,ULONG *OldAddress){
ULONG Address;

DbgPrint("RunHook - NewAddress:0x%00X - Service_Index:0x%0X",NewAddress,Service_Index);

Address = (ULONG)KeServiceDescriptorTable->ServiceTableBase + Service_Index * 4;

*OldAddress = *(ULONG*)Address;


/*__asm
{
    cli
        mov eax, cr0
        and eax, not 10000h
        mov cr0, eax
}*/
__writecr0(__readcr0() & ~0x10000);
// ÐÞ¸ÄSSDTÖÐNtOpenProcess·þÎñµÄµØÖ·
*((ULONG*)Address) = (ULONG)NewAddress;


__asm
{
    mov eax, cr0
        or eax, 10000h
        mov cr0, eax
        sti
}}
```

Comment: `if (1);` should set it to 1.

Comment: Not sure why you have to explicitly set it though, how exactly is your code being applied in the context?

Comment: I Want To Write Driver To Intercept windows Api Calls . i want to hook some Api that i need to intercept them in found This code in kernel mode

Comment: I suppose this is hooking... something? But whatever it is it doesn't look like its hooking APIs. APIs are by definition at application layer, not kernel.

Comment: but This is my main Question How Can i intercept Windows API calls

Comment: Well this is a little something I did a while back, not sure if it will be useful for you. There are many ways to hook an API, depending on exactly what you want to do. https://gist.github.com/Havenard/aa2ee90b14304466eeb3

Comment: It is not a driver, it runs at application level. Make a DLL or something and make the program you want to hook load it.

Comment: Aigh, don't manipulate control registers directly. What if another driver wants it set the opposite way? Use the driver model to declare your intentions to the operating system so it can arbitrate.

Comment: @Havenard : That link is very useFull but How Can i know Which Process call Api

Answer (score 0):

From [MASM for x64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx) in the Visual Studio 2013 documentation:

> Inline ASM is not supported for x64. Use MASM or compiler intrinsics (x64 Intrinsics).

I don't believe that there is any supported way to manipulate the interrupt flag, because by design kernel-mode drivers are [Always Preemptible and Always Interruptible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so to do that you'll need to put the code in a separate module and use MASM.

However, there's little point; in 64-bit Windows, [Kernel Patch Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/Dn613955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) prevents you from modifying the service tables.  You can only hook API calls at the application level, as described in the comments by Havenard.

Comment: Thanks for your help . i know about patchguard in windows 7 x64.
i see some code like Havenard's code,but i don't know how can i find which process call API